# Regex: Find all tags whose words begin with lowercase letters

Tags: regex, windows-10, notepad++

I want to find all `<title>` tags whose words begin with lowercase letters. For example 2 cases:

`<title>My Mother Is Home</title>`

`<title>My mother is home</title>` This is what I want to match using regex, because words like `mother`, `is` or `home` starts with lowercase letters.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: how about this phrase `<title>My mother and I came here</title>` ?

Comment: I have 5000 html files, is not the same title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *could* do, is doing the following:

```
((<title>[^<]+?)([ \t\"][a-z][a-zA-Z_\-\']*\b)|<title>[a-z])
```

Replace by

```
\1REPLACEMENT
```

However, this will only find *the first* non-capital word within the title tag. So you would have to perform the replacement as long as there are occurences found (assumed that you replace the words for uppercase words).

There is no way i can think of getting all words within a title to search&replace them using notepad++.

Comment: I am using notepad++ windows. I cannot execute. Only Search and Replace. Anyway, I try a simple search with your regex, and it finds all words, even if they starts with capital or lowercase letters. :(

Comment: Keep in mind to set the `Match Case` toggle when replacing in notepad++. When you leave the checkbox unchecked, it will find all words, that's true, but there is no regex to avoid this.

Comment: First of all, it has to be specify the <title> tag, otherwise will find all tags from my 5000 html pages.

Comment: Ah, ok, that was too generic then, updating my answer

Comment: your update is great. Works, without Replace. It is enough to give search ;)

Comment: now I see, there is only one problem. If I have a case like this `<title>A Place Where Death Doesn't Exist</title>` Your regex sees `'t` from `Doesn't` as a different word with lowercase letter.

Comment: nope, your update is not so good, because it selects also the words starting with capital and lowercase.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, try that one

Comment: SUPER !! Thanks a lot, Psi !

Comment: uff, I discover another scenario. If I have `<title>Love Between "mother" And "sun"</title>`. Regex is not select this one.

Comment: ;) Updating the answer

Comment: Works, thanks. You can add also `“` `”`  after `\t`, never know

Comment: Nope nope, I check again, sorry, is not working again.  it selects also the words starting with capital and lowercase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138979/discussion-between-psi-and-just-me).